# XML node: add an attribute with a namespace

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to add an attribute into an xml node. I have created the following function

```
  function AddAttribute(xmlNode, attrname, attrvalue, path) {
    var attr;
    if (isIE())
        attr = xmlNode.ownerDocument.createNode(2, attrname, "http://mydomain/MyNameSpace");
    else
        attr = xmlNode.ownerDocument.createAttributeNS("http://mydomain/MyNameSpace", attrname);

    attr.nodeValue = attrvalue;
    var n = xmlNode.selectSingleNode(path);
    n.setAttributeNode(attr);
}
```

This code does not work in Firefox . It adds the node, but it does not add the namespace.
I have tried in IE and in Chrome and it works fine.

Do you know how can I add the namespace? 
Or do you know any other alternative to create an attribute with a namespace?

Thanks

Comment: what do you pass as `attrname`?

Comment: I pass: "co:internalcollectiontype"

Comment: I have found a solution (probably not the best one). I cannot post as an answer, I need to wait 8 hours. until then here is my comment:              


        var n = xmlNode.selectSingleNode(path);
        if (cb.browser.ie) //IE
            n.setAttributeNode(attr); 
        else
            n.setAttributeNodeNS(attr);

Comment: I will add the full function after 8 hours :-o .

Comment: Try `if (xmlNode.ownerDocument.createAttributeNS)`, that would make you independent from browser sniffing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a possible solution. At least it works now for the three browsers : IE, Firefox and Chrome.

```
 function AddAttribute(xmlNode, attrname, attrvalue, path) {
    var attr;
    if (xmlNode.ownerDocument.createAttributeNS)
       attr = xmlNode.ownerDocument.createAttributeNS("http://www.firmglobal.com/MyNameSpace", attrname);
    else
       attr = xmlNode.ownerDocument.createNode(2, attrname, "http://www.firmglobal.com/MyNameSpace");

    attr.nodeValue = attrvalue;
    var n = xmlNode.selectSingleNode(path);

    //Set the new attribute into the xmlNode
    if (n.setAttributeNodeNS)
       n.setAttributeNodeNS(attr);  
    else
        n.setAttributeNode(attr);  
}
```

Thanks to "Tomalak" for his help.