# Duplicate error when adding XAttribute to XElement

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I've got a big xml file and I'm parsing an xpath to insert values in it. This is a part of the xml file where I'm inserting some values:

```
<SERVICES>
    <RELATIONSHIPS>
         <RELATIONSHIP xlink:from="fromValue01" xlink:to="toValue01" />
         <RELATIONSHIP xlink:from="fromValue02" xlink:to="toValue02" />
         <RELATIONSHIP xlink:from="fromValue03" xlink:to="toValue03" />
         <RELATIONSHIP xlink:from="fromValue04" xlink:to="toValue04" />
         <RELATIONSHIP xlink:from="fromValue05" xlink:to="toValue05" />
         <RELATIONSHIP xlink:from="fromValue06" xlink:to="toValue06" />
         <RELATIONSHIP xlink:from="fromValue07" xlink:to="toValue07" />
    </RELATIONSHIPS>
<SERVICES>
```

Now, when I want to add more of these `RELATIONSHIP` nodes with same attributes but with different values (e.g. `<RELATIONSHIP xlink:from="fromValue08" xlink:to="toValue08" />`) I always get a `Duplicate Attribute` error. This would be example of the xpath I'm parsing:

```
/SERVICES/RELATIONSHIPS/RELATIONSHIP[@xlink:from="fromValue08" and @xlink:to="toValue08"]
```

The parser is too big of a code to just paste here, and I'm sure it's working fine since it's inserting all nodes just fine, only this part here is giving me some trouble.
I also checked the xpath with Altova and it works.

My question is: Is adding a node with same attributes but with different values allowed in XML? And if yes, why is Visual Studio always throwing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sure in relation with your XPath request maybe an index in missing for `RELATIONSHIPS`

Comment: Maybe `@xlink:from` instead of `@xlink:fromValue`

Comment: this is also just a part of the real humongous xpath. The xpath is tested in Altova XML Spy and is working fine. Anyways, i fixed it in the question, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: Maybe VS has some troubles to work with XML namespace, try to remove it and test again ?

Comment: It does add the xpath without the xml namespace prefix, but what did I get with that? I need to have that prefix in my attribute.

Comment: `XNamespace` are really a problem while working with `XML` have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160418/xml-node-add-an-attribute-with-a-namespace

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335756/selecting-namespaced-xml-node-attributes-with-namespace-alias-instead-of-uri-on

Comment: I've got it. Event though these links didn't help I accepted your answer. Appreciate your effort. :)

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have figure it out. It wasn't as much of a problem on the parser as it was on the xpath. I was missing an index on the xpath. So my parser was selecting the first `RELATIONSHIP` and it indeed had duplicate XAttributes. I just added the index before the attribute conditions. So in the end it looked something like:

```
/SERVICES/RELATIONSHIPS/RELATIONSHIP[8][@xlink:from="fromValue08" and @xlink:to="toValue08"]
```

I don't know if this is correct xpath syntax, and if the index should come after the conditions but for my parser it's working.